# Pass extra parameter string in WordPress pagination

Tags: wordpress

I want to include extra parameter string, i.e. `param1=val1&param2=var2`, etc in WordPress pagination.

For pagination I am refering the following site code:

http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination

Comment: May be you can find your answer from here.
1.) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114626/pass-additional-parameter-in-the-url
2.) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21794/passing-custom-args-in-paginate-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass as many as parameters inside the custom pagination function like the following :

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='' , $format='' , $tab = '') {
```

And pass the parameters via calling the function,

```
custom_pagination($queryvideos->max_num_pages,6,$paged3,'pagedvideo','videos');
custom_pagination($queryposts->max_num_pages,6,$paged2,'pagedpost','posts');
```

Refer the pagination example here : [Link](http://d34.e06.mwp.accessdomain.com/category/living/)